# why I can receive the old app's push notification when the iphone app reinstall?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, reinstall

uninstall the app first, then reinstall, I can receive the push notification normally.
here is my analysis:
   client uninstalls app, but my provider server has the devicetoken. then reinstall,APNS delivers the same devicetoken to iphone,so when a new push item comes to APNS,it successly delivers the item to the client.
   my app has synchronized devicetoken records with the provider itself,but this problem comes when no launching after reinstall(if the user launch after reinstall,I can remove the register accounts under the devicetoken).how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not ever be delivered until you save the new device token from

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```